# How to display the video from a firebase download URL

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Like for the pictures you can use `Picasso` for example to download the pictures and display them, I need to find a way/a `library` to display videos. I've been looking for a method but  I couldn't find it.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This is a too broad/ off topic question. you need to find in google instead of posted here. fundamental idea is first get url form Notification and then download a video from this URL to your local storage then you try to play video from internal storage.